# How can I make Ctrl-F11 build the project when editing xml in eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I am relatively new to Eclipse. When I build my project in Eclipse, I always press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. This will build the corresponding project and start application when editing a java file, but when you do that while editing xml file, it will create new "out.xml". Is there any way to instruct Eclipse not to do that? Stupid me but I had to delete the unwanted file about 10 times a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a recent version of eclipse.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> will by default try to launch the selected resource. You can change this under

Window->Preferences->Launching

to always launch the last thing you launched.

Comment: Well, it seemed working but I don't think it is what I want. This will make me difficult to launch other projects. For example, when I go to another project, click play button in the toolbar, it will launch the previous project.

Comment: I see. So which version of eclipse are you on? I am on 3.6.2 and I also have the option to choose "Launch the selected ressource or active editor. If not launchable:" "Launch the associated project". That might work for you, though personally I always use "Launch previously launched" and If I want to launch something else I do Ctrl+F7 to package explorer, Ctrl+Shift+/ to collapse and then navigate to what I want to launch and use Alt+Shift+X. They key to your problem is somewhere in that Launching config anyways.